# Program crashes after having received too many send() messages in a short period of time

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

My goal is to write a client-server architecture using TCP sockets in C. I've successfully managed to establish a connection between client and server and send and receive messages in both ways. After receiving a message, the message is being processed by other threads. (It will get enqueued in a queue and another thread works on the queue).

I'm now stress-testing my implementation, by `send()`ing a lot of messages from the client to the server.

So, what it essentially does is:

My client goes in a for loop and sends X messages using `send()` to the server. After exiting the for loop, the connection to the server is `close()`d. This happens all immediately with no delay in between.

The server program works this way: it has a thread where it receives messages and processes the messages by enqueuing them into a queue. After enqueuing it will keep waiting for new messages to arrive. What happens though: The server program will just quit, without any error message, besides that the `recv()` failed (i.e. returning a -1).

I've noticed the following: the server receives maybe 4000 of 5000 messages before the client calls `close()`. If I wait in the client until the server has received all messages before the client calling `close()`, the server does not crash and just continues working. If I don't wait before calling `close()` the server just stops running. No error message and not even the main function of the server will finish (the main function is actually blocked by a `sem_wait()`, until some thread `sem_post()`s the semaphore).

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I make the server to be more robust, even if a client for example crashes during its execution? I don't want the server to be dependent on the client.

Or did I maybe overload the server with sending too many messages with no delay in-between and my scenario is unrealistic?

Here are some parts of my code which are crucial for the send/recv mechanism:

The server:

```c
read_bytes = recv(i, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

// <= 0 bytes read iff client disconnected or error
if (read_bytes <= 0) {
    if(read_bytes == -1) {
        printf("error: recv() failed on port %s\n", port);
    } else {
        if(DEBUG_NETWORKING) printf("server:%s: socket %d disconnected\n", port, i);
    }

    // Disconnect and remove from master set
    close(i);
    FD_CLR(i, &master_set);
}

// Client wants to tell us something!
else {

    // Test if forcefully connected
    test = (int) buffer[0];

    if(test != 4) { // If it's NOT the EOT character (dec val =4), thus a "real message"
        if(DEBUG_NETWORKING) printf("server:%s: received from socket %d (%i bytes) : %s\n", port, i, read_bytes, buffer);
        // Now call the data handler function that was provided with the function call of connections_handler()
        handler(buffer, read_bytes, i, port);
    }

    // This happens if the client forcefullys quits the process
    // without sending a disconnect signal (it actually sends an EOT character)
    // Catch here this bug.
    else {
        if(DEBUG_NETWORKING) printf("server:%s: socket %d will disconnect forcefully\n", port, i);
    }
}
```

The client

```c
int rand_item_id;
int rand_amount;
int action;
char msg[256] = "";
int i=0;

while(1) {
    i++;
    if(i==5000) break;
    if (atoi(argv[2]) != 0) {
        usleep(atoi(argv[2]));
    }

    rand_item_id = rand() % atoi(argv[3]);

    // either buy or get, 50/50% chance
    action = rand() % 2;
    if(action == 0) {
        // BUY
        rand_amount = rand() % 20;
        sprintf(msg, "BUY item_%i %i\n", i, rand_amount);
    } else {
        // GET
        sprintf(msg, "GET item_%i\n", i);
    }
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
}

//sleep(10);
close(sock);
```

Comment: What is `msg`? Where does it crash?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've added the vars definition above. The crash is weird. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't. I couldn't pinpoint where it exactly happens since it happens at different places (or the last prinf I'll get in the console always differs). It will surely happen if I increase the amount of messages (i.e. i==10000) and comment the sleep() at the end of the client.

Comment: Run the debug build with the debugger. When the crash happens, the debugger will tell you exactly where it happened. And what is the error message of the crash?

Comment: `send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);` may be sending 1 less byte then it needs to.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've compiled now the file using the -g flag and run the program. However, it didn't generate any core dump in my /cores/ directory (I'm on macOS). There is no error message. I've even tried using errno but no luck

Comment: @albxn Don't just use `-g`, run the server *in the debugger*.  Then when it crashes the debugger will stop exactly where it happened.

Comment: @dbush Oh, okey. Sorry. Here is the report I got: `Process 23847 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) Terminated due to signal 13`

Comment: No, no... please... read [how to create a complete, minimal and reproducible example here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then edit your code to be compilable and executable _out of the box_.  If we have to patch your code in order to be able to test it, we'll probably solve the errors you can have and see nothing at all.  We cannot guess what is a typo or what is an error.  Don't post what you think is the problem, because if you knew what is the problem there would be no need for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is terminating from signal 13 which is `SIGPIPE`.  This signal is typically only used if you want to do asynchronous I/O, i.e. when you get the signal then you read.

You have a message loop that is always waiting for messages, so you don't care about this signal.  So set up the signal handler to ignore it.

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: There are multiple threads opening each a socket on a different port. Should I call this for every thread, i.e. inside the thread function or should I call this at the beginning of my server's main function?

Comment: @albxn Do it once at program startup.  The signal mask will apply to all thread.

Comment: Rather than using `signal()`, another way to disable `SIGPIPE` on a per-socket basic is to use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_SIGNOPIPE)`, or the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag on `send(to)` and `recv(from)`